# ¿Cómo hacer que el código recorra el árbol binario en su totalidad?

Tags: java, árboles-binarios

El código que estoy haciendo acerca de cómo encontrar un NODO en un ÁRBOL BINARIO no funciona, me sirve solo para los nodos que se encuentran directamente a la izquierda de la RAÍZ del arbol.

A continuación escribo el código

```
public Nodo encontrarNodo(Nodo raiz, String dato){

        if(raiz!=null){
                if(raiz.getIzquierda()!=null){

                    if(dato.equals(raiz.getDato())){

                        return raiz;
                    }else{
                        return encontrarNodo(raiz.getIzquierda(), dato);
                    }
                }

                if(raiz.getDerecha()!=null){
                    if(dato.equals(raiz.getDato())){
                            return raiz;
                    } else{
                            return encontrarNodo(raiz.getDerecha(), dato);
                    }   
                }
        }

        return null;


    }
```

Comment: Estás en SO en español, no hay necesidad de escribir en inglés

Comment: https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/Java/2257-Arboles-binarios-de-busqueda.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ver si un dato está en el árbol, el dato tiene que estar en la raíz, en su subárbol izquierdo o en su subárbol derecho.

Dicho de otra forma:

- Si el árbol está vacío, el dato no puede estar en el árbol.
- Si el dato está en la raíz, entonces he encontrado el nodo.
- Si no está en la raíz, entonces hay que mirar en el subárbol izquierdo (recursividad)
- Si no está en el subárbol izquierdo, hay que mirar en el subárbol derecho. (recursividad)
- Si no está en el subárbol derecho (y por lo tanto tampoco en el izquierdo, ni en la raíz) es que el dato no está en el árbol.

Pasando esto a código:

```
public Nodo encontrarNodo(Nodo raiz, String dato) {
  Nodo retval;
  if (raiz == null) {
     retval = null; // Árbol vacío o callejón sin salida.
  } else {
     if (dato.equals(raiz.getDato()) {
        retval = raiz; // El dato está en la raíz.
     } else {
        Nodo izq = encontrarNodo(raiz.getIzquierda(), dato);
        if (izq == null) {
           Nodo der = encontrarNodo(raiz.getDerecha(), dato);
           if (der == null) {
             retval = null; // El dato no se ha encontrado
           }  else {
             retval = der; // El dato estaba en algún nodo del subárbol derecho
           }
        } else {
           retval = izq; // El dato estaba en algún nodo del subárdbol izquierdo
        }
     }
  }
  return retval;
}
```